# Facebook share dialog callback not working in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, share

I'm implementing the share dialog using the Facebook SDK for iOS.
Everything works fine except for the callback.
This is the function that displays the dialog:

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
    content.contentURL = <my content url>;
    content.contentTitle = <my title>;
    content.contentDescription = my description;
    content.imageURL = <my image url>;
    [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self
                                 withContent:content
                                    delegate:self];
```

The view controller implements the FBSDKSharingDelegate and the three required methods:

```
- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results;

- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;

- (void)sharerDidCancel:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer;
```

Basically I have to detect if users pressed the cancel button because I give them a reward only if they effectively share the content. 
The problem is that even if I press the cancel button the only callback that is invoked is:

```
- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results;
```

and not

```
- (void)sharerDidCancel:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer;
```

as expected. Furthermore using iOS8 the variable *results* is empty if the cancel button is pressed, otherwise it contains the post_id, but this does not happen with iOS7, where the result is **always** empty.

What am I doing wrong? What am I supposed to do to have the *sharerDidCancel* callback working properly?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: _“because I give them a reward only if they effectively share the content”_ – you are __not allowed__ to reward users for sharing. Please go read [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy) – 4.5 says, _“Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions.”_

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much  for that I didn't know it. Anyway the problem now persist. Any idea how could I resolve it?

Comment: @Prem, I am also facing the same issue. do you have any solution for this?

Comment: Nope. It's only working on iPhone 6 or greater actually. I could not find a way to have it working on iPhone 5s / 5 / 4s etc...

Comment: If you use the FBSDKShareDialog display mode as FBSDKShareDialogModeWeb,It can solve this problem.Hope it helpful.

Comment: If you use the FBSDKShareDialog display mode as FBSDKShareDialogModeWeb,It can solve this problem.But it only can used to share link,but not support to share photo.Hope it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try entering this to your appdelegate. It worked for me to call the right delegate but the result dictionary is still empty and I can't get the post_id.

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                              didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                    openURL:url
                                          sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                 annotation:annotation];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lorenzo, I'm gonna try it!